# Select2 en Django

Tags: django, django-forms, select2

Estoy agregando un campo con select2 y no me aparecen los nombre pero si los espacios de los clientes creados:

[image: campo en blanco]

Mi template html

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <select name="clientes" id="clientes">
                    <option value="0">Seleccione cliente</option>
                        {% for cliente in clientes %}
                            <option value="0"> {{ clientes.nombre_empresa }} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

---

Al poner en el for {{ clientes.1 }} me muestra lo siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="row">
            <div>
                <select name="clientes" id="clientes">
                    <option value="0">Seleccione cliente</option>
                        {% for cliente in clientes %}
                            <option> {{ clientes.1 }} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
            </div>
         </div>
```

Esto debería mostrar una lista:
 -Empresa1
 -Empresa2
 -Empresa3

He buscado información y no he encontrado algo referente a esto.

Comment: Hola pepex7, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow. Por favor completa el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio.

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple vista el problema se debe a que no estas usando la variable correcta.

La variable `cliente` (*en singular*) es la que guarda la información de la empresa.
También tene en cuenta que no estas indicando un `value` correcto para los `option`.

### Solución:

Usar la variable `cliente` y, suponiendo que `id_empresa` es el **ID**, imprimir dicho valor en el `value`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <select name="clientes" id="clientes">
        <option value="0">Seleccione cliente</option>
        {% for cliente in clientes %}
        <option value="{{ cliente.id_empresa }}"> {{ cliente.nombre_empresa }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos por tu respuesta.

Lo probaré.